# Flutter is faster in debug-mode than when released

Tags: android, performance, flutter, kotlin, dart

**SOLVED! See julemand101's comments!**

I am testing out flutter and have run into a small "problem". The application seems to execute instructions much quicker in Debug-mode than it does when released, and I am wondering why this is.

When i run the app using "flutter run", these are the times (in milliseconds) it takes to sort 10 000, 25 000, and 50 000 integers using Bubble Sort:
[Debug Mode Times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuNmj.png)

When i run the app using "flutter run --release", the sorting times get increasingly worse, see image:
[Released App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yQND.png)

I have just started learning Flutter, so I garantue a lot of things are going to be subpar, but here is the code I use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String results = "";

  void _runTests() {
    results = "";
       
    var arr = loadArray(10000);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
    bubbleSort(arr);
    timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    String bubble10k = "Bubble Sort 10k: $timeTaken \n";

    arr = loadArray(25000);
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
    bubbleSort(arr);
    timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    String bubble25k = "Bubble Sort 25k: $timeTaken \n";

    arr = loadArray(50000);
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
    bubbleSort(arr);
    timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    String bubble50k = "Bubble Sort 50k: $timeTaken \n";

     
    setState(() {
      results += 
          bubble10k +
          bubble25k +
          bubble50;
    });
  }

  loadArray(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var rand = new Random();
    while (arr.length < n) {
      var r = rand.nextInt(1000000);
      arr.add(r);
    }
    return arr;
  }

  bubbleSort(var array) {
    int lengthOfArray = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfArray - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          // Swapping using temporary variable
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    return (array);
  }

  insertionSort(var arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
      int key = arr[i];
      int j = i - 1;

      while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        j = j - 1;
      }
      arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Results: ',
            ),
            Text(
              '$results',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _runTests,
        tooltip: 'Start',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is, or what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the code you have written? Also, `flutter run` is not "Debug mode" but rather running the application with the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler which in some situations can actually be faster (since it can make optimizations based on the code and runtime) but does take some time before it is "warmed up". The "release" will compile the application using Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compilation where optimizations is purely based on the code and not runtime.

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you for your response. I have now updated the questions with the code I am using. Is there a way around to achieve the same "efficency" with AOT compilation, or is this simply not possible?

Comment: You can start helping the compiler by making your code more type safe. Right now, there are a lot of `dynamic` typing. Also, port your code to nullsafety to make it even more type safe.

Comment: Will do that! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is just an example of the performance of your benchmark I gets after I have added statically typing. The code is compatible with Dart 2.12

I should add that I needed to rewrite the code so I could run it outside of the Flutter framework since I am not using Flutter. But the results should be more or less the same:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  var arr = loadArray(10000);
  Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  bubbleSort(arr);
  var timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
  print("Bubble Sort ${arr.length}: $timeTaken");

  arr = loadArray(25000);
  stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  bubbleSort(arr);
  timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
  print("Bubble Sort ${arr.length}: $timeTaken");

  arr = loadArray(50000);
  stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  bubbleSort(arr);
  timeTaken = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
  print("Bubble Sort ${arr.length}: $timeTaken");
}

final _random = Random();

List<int> loadArray(int n) => List.generate(n, (_) => _random.nextInt(1000000));

List<int> bubbleSort(List<int> array) {
  final lengthOfArray = array.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfArray - i - 1; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
        // Swapping using temporary variable
        final temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}

List<int> insertionSort(List<int> arr) {
  final n = arr.length;

  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    final key = arr[i];
    var j = i - 1;

    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      j = j - 1;
    }
    arr[j + 1] = key;
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Output when using `dart run` (JIT):

```
>dart run stackoverflow.dart
Bubble Sort 10000: 172
Bubble Sort 25000: 1201
Bubble Sort 50000: 4420
```

Output when running executable created by `dart compile exe` (AOT):

```
>dart compile exe stackoverflow.dart
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
Generated: stackoverflow.exe

>stackoverflow.exe
Bubble Sort 10000: 231
Bubble Sort 25000: 1597
Bubble Sort 50000: 5885
```

It should be noted that this kind of benchmark is kinda pointless since they are not really telling the whole story about the performance. E.g. JIT can start slower but get some speed after some time when using a method a lot of times.

Also, use the `sort()` method on your `List` if you need to sort it since that is way faster ;)

```
JIT: List.sort 50000: 26
AOT: List.sort 50000: 19
```